# Why are my Google AppEngine instances crashing with 'error code 121'?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been running a java high-replication web application on Google AppEngine for some time now. About two days ago - basically out of nowhere - a lot of requests began to fail with **HTTP status 500** and **error code 121**, meaning that the respective GAE instance crashes or is shut down.

Here is an exemplary log entry, which I now have tons of:

```
2013-02-15 06:44:00.909 /api 500 3770ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17
###.###.###.### - - [14/Feb/2013:22:44:00 -0800] "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17" "###.########.###" ms=3770 cpu_ms=1191 exit_code=121 instance=00c61b117c2c2b8fd8c433bc45a62183829f6484

W 2013-02-15 06:44:00.652
    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 121)
```

The error sometimes occurs right within a 'warmup' request, thus when a new instance receives its first request. An associated log entry looks like this:

```
2013-02-15 06:40:02.779 /_ah/warmup 500 2970ms 0kb
0.1.0.3 - - [14/Feb/2013:22:40:02 -0800] "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - - "2013-02-14-1438.flox-by-gamua.appspot.com" ms=2971 cpu_ms=671 loading_request=1 exit_code=121 instance=00c61b117c48cb17ea555d1988c0db473c2390

I 2013-02-15 06:40:02.437
    This request caused a new process to be started for your application and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
W 2013-02-15 06:40:02.437
    A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 121)
```

I have been searching the web for this problem and it looks like it happened before: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7348.

Since all relevant issues have been marked as 'resolved', I did file a new GAE production issue over here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8812

**Edit 2013-04-29:** The link above does not work anymore since this issue has been flagged as 'Restricted' by the GAE team.

Unfortunately, my cries for help went unnoticed for over two days now. That's why I am, in my utter desperation, asking for your help!

**Does anyone know what's causing error code 121? Is there some form of documentation? Is something wrong with my app? Is there a way to nudge the AppEngine team to have a look into this issue?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you tell us if your app is Java, python or Go?

Comment: Nick, sorry for forgetting about that: It's Java.

Comment: Hi, Holger, does this error go away by itself? Today (1 hour ago), I have exactly same issue (error code 121) like yours.  My app is running  fine from one month ago, but get this error just now. However, my app is on python27/HRD.

Comment: Yes. At least in my case these errors went away after a few days. I do not know what they did, but one day the errors were gone.

They come back in rare intervals but they do not pile up like when I was first creating this question.

Also, I still do NOT know why they occur...

Comment: Since two hours we are back to 121s - and a lot of them. Same pattern: No changes from our side could have triggered these errors.

Comment: We are experiencing the same problem with Java/HRD, @Holger how about the situation about your app?

Comment: Same problem here on python27 HRD...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to reply but I have a specific use case that seems interesting:

- python27
- hrd
- dynamic backed configured with 8 instances

Everything works as expected, except for one instance, instance=2, which basically cycles

- '/_ah/start'
- (Error code 121)
- '/_ah/stop'

Backends allows you to address a specific instance such as 2.backendname.appname.appspot.com and apparently something is wrong with that instance.

I suppose it's reassuring to know that there's one bad instance that's repeatedly failing due to a vague error code, instead of many instances failing randomly due to a vague error code.  It'd be more reassuring if that instance were dropped, etc particularly if it's cycling this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Check your log retention limits, and that you haven't exceeded them.  You wouldn't expect that bypassing your log retention limits would cause an exception that caused the instance to fail, but after I increased mine, I stopped seeing this error crop up and my backend cron jobs were able to complete.

Comment: Nebulae, thanks for your answer! I do not yet understand how I should be working with this: If I increase the log retention limits I will get bigger logs. These logs will eventually have to be deleted at some point. So I assume this is just a temporary fix, since I have not yet found a way to delete logs manually. Is this possible?

Comment: Nebulae, I just tested your log retention trick by doubling my retention limits. It does not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have not seen anything for sure about this from Google. They are often shy to explain such issues. One of the threads do mention datastore migration. See if that helps;

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7022

Comment: My app is already using the high-replication datastore. So, the MS can't be the reason for the errors. Sorry for not mentioning that in the post.

Comment: I see. By the way, I experienced two strange behaviours with App Engine. 1) Could not get into the Logs for my app for a while 2) Could not delete anything from the datastore using the application. I redeployed in app and after a while things worked fine. As you said, your issue just cropped up, it might go away by itself. Only Google can answer why this is happening. All the best

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, the web interface does work fine for me. Also redeploying did not help fix the errors. That was my first guess, too. Thanks again.